# SQL: Optimized variable usage in case clause

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

I'm rewriting some SQL code that generates a "bucket" column based on the current month (that happens to be stored as VARCHAR, ugh).

I noticed that the previous author decided to store a certain number of dates for comparison as variables, and then use a case statement to calculate the bucket.

See SQL Fiddle [Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3367b/1) that demonstrates a slice of this (it happens about five times in three different ways similar to this).

Is there any reason I cannot simply get rid of most of the redundant variables and simplify it to a few lines of code (See [This Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3367b/3))? Is the overhead of in-line function calls great enough to justify doing this, or does the query compiler cache the results of that portion anyways?